# how to hide drupal footprints form a site

Tags: browser, drupal, drupal-7, cross-browser

I don't like others simply realize that the site which I have created is made by Drupal or other CMSs. I know it's inevitable by some plugins like Wappalyzer in Firefox comming into play. But now I need to make it a bit harder so that at least amateurs can not realize it.

now if you right click on the site and select view page info in Firefox it will say that it is a Drupal site.!

how can I make it harder to realize?

Comment: Hmm...just hiding word "Drupal" wont' help much - it's more complicated than that. You would have to re-organize whole file placement. I.e. back-end uploaded file are stored in /sites/default/files ....theme files are in /sites/all/themes.....all that says that it's drupal site...

Comment: you are absolutely right. but how can I prevent browser from showing this in page info? just this

Comment: It must be somewhere in template files. Start from html.tpl.php and then check on page.tpl.php ...it must be somewhere inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are you talking about the generator meta tag. This is added by the metatag module by default. Go into the settings for metatags (admin/config/search/metatags) and set the generator tag to an empty string.

But if you really want to stop people knowing its a drupal site, it's going to be much much harder.
Things off the top of my head that would indicate a drupal site are:

CHANGELOG.txt in the root of the site.
X-Drupal-Cache header.
Expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT header.
Path to theme css and js files.
Actually, the path to any file on the site.

So I wouldn't even bother trying to hide the fact that its Drupal.

To remove the generator meta tag without the metatag module, add this to your theme template.php file (changing YOURTHEME to the name of your theme).

```
function YOURTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  unset($head_elements['system_meta_generator']);
}
```

Comment: yes you are right... that's too hard to do. It was better if I could prevent firefox browser from saying my cms. now if you right click on the site and choose view page info. you would see that it is a drupal 7. :(

Comment: Like I said, that is probably the generator tag implemented by the metatag module. Just set it to an empty string in the settings. None of my sites say anything about Drupal when looking at page info in firefox. because I disabled the generator tag.

Comment: Does you page have the generator metatag output in the source ?

Comment: How about you just show me the page or a screenshot of how firefox is telling you the page is drupal.

Comment: I couldn't add a screenshot because of my reputation. you can test it yourself at http://epopads.com/test2/ . thanks

Comment: ok, like I said, you have a generator meta tag. I have updated my answer to show how to remove it.